# LinearSearch returning wrong result

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have implemented a lets say inefficient version of linear search but I keep running into problems while testing the algorithm, for some reason for every 10 different tests, 2-3 tend to give invalid results. I am testing this vs .net Contains, i.e.:

```
Test 1:
LinearSearch(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, 4)        : true
(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}.Contains(4)            : true

Test 2: 
LinearSearch(new int[] {5,6,7,8,9}, 6)        : true
(new int[] {5,6,7,8,9}.Contains(6)            : true

Test 2:
LinearSearch(new int[] {10,11,12,13,14}, 13)  : false
(new int[] {10,11,12,13,14}.Contains(13)      : true
```

Although this is just an example and is not how I test anything. Is mainly to demonstrate the sequence in which I am testing the algorithm.

Moving on here is my implementation(not the full version, just the part where I am having problems):

```
    public static int Search(T[] elements, T item)
    {
        int result = -1;
        int length = elements.Length;
        int half = elements.Length / 2;

        bool upperBoundG = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(elements[elements.Length - 1], item) > 0;
        bool upperBoundQ = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(elements[elements.Length - 1], item) == 0;

        if (!upperBoundG)
            return -1;

        else if (upperBoundQ)
            return elements.Length - 1;

        else
        {
            for (int j = 0, i = half - 1; j < half && i < length; j++, i++)
            {
                result = elements[j].Equals(item) ? j : elements[i].Equals(item) ? i : -1;
                if (result != -1) break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

This is not the entire algorithm, this is the search method which is whats causing the problem, specifically within the loop.

The algorithm is based on the standard linear search of setting the key to -1, loop through the collection and if found set the key to i and return i else -1, but instead of doing this the old fashion way I chose to compare the last element of the array to the element we're searching for, the reason being that I would like to avoid searching the wrong array if the item is greater or if its the equal set the key to (length - 1) and end it there. Within the loop I split the search method by iterating twice within the same loop, where the first iteration is from 0-mid and the second from mid-end(minus the last item).

Now that the description is over, I would like to point out that the error has to be definitely here:

```
result = collection[j].Equals(item) ? j : collection[i].Equals(item) ? i : -1;
```

Although I am not 100% sure that this is the part of the code giving me such results, so if you guys don't really see anything wrong here and require a bit more I will add more examples.

PS: this is not homework or anything of the sort, basically is just for learning purposes. I know many have tried this before and some of you may find the question pointless but I got curious and wanted to know whether I could come up with an efficient Linear Search, at least as fast as Contains (if possible).

Comment: Now, lets just for a moment assume that you search for the last element. `upperBoundG` would be `false` in this case and you return `-1`, right? Also it appears as if `LinearSearch` is completely missing, so there's no way to execute your example code (MCVE - verifiable?)

Comment: Most of the issues originate from your `for` loop. It's unclear why you need 2 indexes (the standard linear search is simple `for (int i - 0; i < length; i++)`). Your algorithm is double checking some indexes and missing others. For instance, with 5 elements it's checking (0, 1) and (1, 2) indexes. It would be a bit better if you start with `i = half` but it will miss the last index when the length is odd. Shortly, it's dead algorithm.

Comment: @grek40 you don't really need LinearSearch, just Search - I wrote that thinking the name was still LinearSearch when is just **Search**, @Ivan Stoev I can clearly see what you mean and i've changed `i = half - 1` to `i = half` and now it works, no incorrect results, as you said this would not work for an array or collection of short length, so thanks for the tip, but I do not think is a dead algorithm and will keep improving it until I either realize this for myself (if it turns out it is) or make something amazing, but thanks non the less.